# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement :Google play

Tags: codenameone

The error message I get is:
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APK or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 180.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More. The Start to roll out button is then disabled.

I am guessing I used a cn1lib which is not 64bit compliant or some native code which is not 
I have the following libraries installed

- QR Maker.cn1lib
- QR Scanner.cn1lib
- Zip Support.cn1lib
- cn1-codescan.cn1lib

The following is the native code I have on:
[image: stack1]

Answer (score 0):

Codename One, the native code you used and 3 of these libraries are in Java which means they support all Android platforms.

The only exception is `QRScanner.cn1lib` which was updated to support 64 bit and fix quite a few issues ages ago so I doubt it has a problem. It's possible you have something from an older version of that library still in your system. Try [uninstalling it](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-uninstall-cn1lib.html) and see if this resolves the issue. Assuming it does try re-installing it with a fresh copy.